# Finding $f(1)$ from the given integral function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Consider the function-
>   $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } x\in[-1,1]\\ 0, \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$
>
> and $$f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}g(y)dy$$
>
> then what is the value of $f(1)?$

My attempt:

We get, $$f(1)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g(y)dy$$

Applying Newton-Leibnitz for the nuemerator after applying L'Hopital for this $0/0$ limit, we get

$$f(1)=\frac{g(1+h)+g(1-h)}{2}=1$$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function under limit is an even function of $h$ it is sufficient to deal with $h\to 0^{+}$ only.

We have $$\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g(y)\,dy=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{1-h}^{1}g(y)\,dy$$ The integral evaluates to $h$ and hence the above limit is $1/2$.

Your approach is fine but the issue is that you seem to assume $g$ continous at $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I had gone blind while solving this to miss out on the real trivial part

Answer (score 4):

You are replacing the wrong variable in your solution.

$$
f(1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g(y)dy.
$$

Now, for each fixed $h<2$,

$$
\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g(y)dy=1-(1-h)=h.
$$

Thus,

$$
f(1)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{2h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(1)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g(y)dy = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{1-h}^{1}g(y)dy = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2h}(1-(1-h)) ={1\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The two sided limit, $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}~g(1+h)$, does not exist because $g(x)$ is discontinuous in $x=1$. (To be more specific, we are dealing with a jump discontinuity.) This will cause problems when computing $f(1)$.

If we would to take the one-sided limit from above, then we would get $lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}~g(1+h) = 0$ and $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+}~g(1-h) = 1$.

I have not done the full derivation but I am guessing the final answer would be $f(1)=1/2$.

I hope this helps you out enough, good luck solving the math problem!

Comment: A jump discontinuity is no problem for an integral.  For any $h \lt  2$ we have the computation of $f(1)$ at that $h$ is $\frac 12$, so the limit as $h \to 0$ is $\frac 12$